# JSON each loop not working. How to resolve?

Tags: jquery, json

jQuery:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].ID);
});
```

response JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "ID":"33",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"9",
      "Item":"ds 18 sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84212120",
      "Quantity":"110",
      "Purchase_rate":"85",
      "Discount":"0",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"85",
      "CGST_Percentage":"9",
      "SGST_Percentage":"9",
      "IGST_Percentage":"0",
      "Rate_after_tax":"100.3",
      "CGST":"841.5",
      "SGST":"841.5",
      "IGST":"0",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"9350",
      "Net_amount":"11033",
      "Item_id":"25"
   },
   {  
      "ID":"42",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"16",
      "Item":"ds 18 sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84212120",
      "Quantity":"1000",
      "Purchase_rate":"10",
      "Discount":"0",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"10",
      "CGST_Percentage":"9",
      "SGST_Percentage":"9",
      "IGST_Percentage":"0",
      "Rate_after_tax":"11.8",
      "CGST":"900",
      "SGST":"900",
      "IGST":"0",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"10000",
      "Net_amount":"11800",
      "Item_id":"25"
   }
]
```

Anyone can please tell me why it appearing error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. How can I resolve it? and by using each loop how can I get data? sorry for my weak English. Thanks in advance. please edit this question so it can help others.

Comment: The each is passing in the index and the element at that index.  Why are you accessing data[i] instead of item?

Comment: Invalid or unexpected token may be pointing out invalid json for the parse of the json.

Comment: alert(item.ID) should work

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me.

```js
var data = [  
   {  
      "ID":"33",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"9",
      "Item":"ds 18 sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84212120",
      "Quantity":"110",
      "Purchase_rate":"85",
      "Discount":"0",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"85",
      "CGST_Percentage":"9",
      "SGST_Percentage":"9",
      "IGST_Percentage":"0",
      "Rate_after_tax":"100.3",
      "CGST":"841.5",
      "SGST":"841.5",
      "IGST":"0",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"9350",
      "Net_amount":"11033",
      "Item_id":"25"
   },
   {  
      "ID":"42",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"16",
      "Item":"ds 18 sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84212120",
      "Quantity":"1000",
      "Purchase_rate":"10",
      "Discount":"0",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"10",
      "CGST_Percentage":"9",
      "SGST_Percentage":"9",
      "IGST_Percentage":"0",
      "Rate_after_tax":"11.8",
      "CGST":"900",
      "SGST":"900",
      "IGST":"0",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"10000",
      "Net_amount":"11800",
      "Item_id":"25"
   }
];

$.each(data, function(index, item){ console.log(item.ID); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var data = [  
   {  
      "ID":"33",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"9",
      "Item":"ds 18 sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84212120",
      "Quantity":"110",
      "Purchase_rate":"85",
      "Discount":"0",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"85",
      "CGST_Percentage":"9",
      "SGST_Percentage":"9",
      "IGST_Percentage":"0",
      "Rate_after_tax":"100.3",
      "CGST":"841.5",
      "SGST":"841.5",
      "IGST":"0",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"9350",
      "Net_amount":"11033",
      "Item_id":"25"
   },
   {  
      "ID":"42",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"16",
      "Item":"ds 18 sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84212120",
      "Quantity":"1000",
      "Purchase_rate":"10",
      "Discount":"0",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"10",
      "CGST_Percentage":"9",
      "SGST_Percentage":"9",
      "IGST_Percentage":"0",
      "Rate_after_tax":"11.8",
      "CGST":"900",
      "SGST":"900",
      "IGST":"0",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"10000",
      "Net_amount":"11800",
      "Item_id":"25"
   }
]

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    console.log(data[i].ID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```